# Why is $ProcessorCount different than the selected number of cores in PBS?

Tags: parallelization, kernel, remote-access, high-performance-clusters

By using [`ParallelTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelTable.html) and submitting my Mathematica code to a cluster, I noticed that it was enhancing the speed even when I selected a **single core** in a **single node**, comparing to the use of standard `Table`. Verifying the number of cores using `$ProcessorCount`, I got 16.

For selecting the number of cores I have submitted a bash file in terminal (already logged in SSH) using

```
qsub -I run_inter.sh
```

The file "run_inter.sh" contains

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -l walltime=10:00:00

#PBS -q par32
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
```

where "par32" is a machine with 32GB of RAM.

Is there any reason for Mathematica to ignore the specification of core number and use 16 anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PBS specifications do not get sent to Mathematica. PBS doesn't control Mathematica. Your job is being run on a machine with 16 cores and Mathematica sees this, hence the result of `$ProcessorCount`.

To limit Mathematica to a single core, add the following lines to your script

```
SetSystemOptions["MKLThreads" -> 1]
SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1]
```

This will not affect the result of `$ProcessorCount`

Comment: Thank you. So, the option `nodes= :ppn= ` is useless when using Mathematica? How can I choose the number of nodes in the cluster?

Comment: Its a two step process, `#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1` tells your cluster that you intend to use one core and `SetSystemOptions["MKLThreads" -> 1]
SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1]` ensures that you really do only use one core

Comment: You can control the number of kernels used in ParallelTable using LaunchKernels[].  So, LaunchKernels[4] uses four for example.

Comment: But, for example, that machine has nodes with 16 cores each. If I want to use 20 cores (10 for each node), I should use `#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=10` plus what? `LaunchKernels[20]` ?

Comment: If you want to launch kernels across nodes, you or your sysadmin has a lot more work to do.  Wolfram lightweight grid may be of use http://www.wolfram.com/lightweight-grid-manager/ but might be a lot of work to make it play nicely with PBS.  I'm not sure...never done it. Life will be *much* easier for you if you just batch your work into several independent 16 core jobs